# Fluent nHibernate - Saves some interfaces, and not others

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I've run into a strange error in fluent nhibernate. I have a basic set of classes that inherit from interfaces, and I have mapped the interfaces to tables, and where classes utilize these, they implement a generic of the interface. They are defined as follows;

```
interface IPage {
  // properties
}

class IPageMap : ClassMap<IPage> {
 // mapping information
}

class Page : IPage {
 // IPage Implementation
}

class ITag {
  // properties
}

class ITagMap : ClassMap<ITag> {
  // mapping information
}

class Tag : ITag {
  // ITag implementation
}

class Template {
  virtual IList<IPage> Pages { get; set; }
  virtual IList<ITag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

This should work fine. When I create an object like this ...

```
var pages = new List<IPage> {
   new Page {
     // ..
   }
}

pages.ForEach( x => { session.SaveOrUpdate(x); } ); // no exception here

var tags = new List<ITag> {
   new Tag { 
     // ... 
   }
}

tags.ForEach( x => { session.SaveOrUpdate(x); } ); // exception happens here.

var list = new List<Template> {
  new Template {
     Pages = new List<IPage> {
       new Page { 
          // ... 
       }
     },
     Tags = new List<ITag> {
       new Tag { 
          // .. 
       }
     }
   }
}
```

I am given the following exception.

> There is no persister for `Tag`

Okay, I didn't define a persister for `Tag`, but I did for `ITag`, and `Tag` inherits it. `IPage` and `Page` work the same way. If I comment out the tag information and just leave the `IPage` and `Page` implementation, it works fine for those.

Why is `ITag` and `Tag` being treated differently? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to map `Tag` as a subclass of `ITag`. Every persistent type needs to be mapped separately, you need to tell NH where the members of the subclass are going to (even if there aren't any) and more importantly which concrete type NH should instantiate when reading the data from the database.

Comment: Okay, that's fine - but why didn't I have to do that with `Page`? I didn't map it as a sublcass and it still works.

Comment: I can't see any difference it what you tell me here. There must be a difference somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, hence my complete confusion. e.e

Comment: But by removing "everything else" you can't find the difference. Your question actually says: "I have two equal cases. What's the difference?" How should I know?

Comment: I figured out the issue. You were right about the mapping. Here is what happened. When I would create new `IPage` elements, they would be in another object's collection. This meant the specific relationship mapping was specified in that object's map graph. However if I tried to create an `IPage` standalone, it would fail. I simply presumed because I didn't have any failures before the `ITag` list that the `IPage` ones were working the same way.

Comment: I suspected something like this.